# Pulling out player's position per second in game maker

Tags: game-maker

I am making a game in gamemaker, I need to pull out player's position or coordinates per second in text file or excel sheet or CSV file. I am new to gamemaker and I don't know much about how to pull out  information from the game. 
I would really appreciate any help in this matter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Game Maker's File I/O is not the best. However, since there are 30 steps in each second (by default, you can make sure in Room > Settings), you can make a script to record the object.x and object.y every 30 steps (or even every step, for that matter). I'm not sure if you want to input or output from file, so if you explain more I can probably expand on this.

**Edit #1**

In your first room's creation code, put this:

```
globalvar playersteps;
playersteps=0;
```

Then in your player object, put this in a code snippet in the Step Event (**replace objectname with the object's name in the code**):

```
var file;
file = file_text_open_write(working_directory + "\log.txt")

if (playersteps) { playersteps -= 1 } else {
file_text_write_real(file,objectname.x)
file_text_write_string(file,",")
file_text_write_real(file,objectname.y)
file_text_writeln(file)
playersteps=30
}

file_text_close(file)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I think you got my question correctly. I need to output the x and y coordinates everytime any player is playing the game. I need to record the player's x and y coordinates along with the time, in an excel sheet or text file. I need to export this after every session in order to analyze the data. i would really appreciate if you can help me how to export or output this data from the game maker.

Comment: @Aks I've edited in some code that should work. It makes a comma-separated list of x and y, tell me if you want me to edit the format used to log it.

Comment: @ Timtech.... Thank you so much!!!!!I really appreciate your help. I pasted the code(globalvar playersteps playersteps=0) in the room's creation code but it is not recognizing playersteps=0... its saying-> ERROR at line 2 pos 13: Unexpected symbol in expression. What should I do about it? Thank you once again...

Comment: @Aks, try now, with the semicolons that I added.

Comment: @Timtech...Thank you for your reply. I tried to run the code again using the changes you made in the code. But now during running the code its shows the error that---

ERROR in
action number 1
of  Step Event0
for object obj_helicopter:

File not opened for writing.
 at gml_Object_obj_helicopter_StepNormalEvent_1 (line 6) - file_text_write_string(file,string(obj_helicopter.x)+","+string(obj_helicopter.y))...... what changes should be made? Kindly help!

Comment: @Aks I edited it a bit (so please re-copy the second part), now all you have to do is create an empty text file called log.txt in the same directory as your game.

Comment: @Timtech...Thank you once again for your help.The changes you made in the code does help to create a log(text file) in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\gamename\\log.txt but when I open the text file it is empty. Why do you think its happening? I really appreciate all the help you have done so far.

Comment: @Aks You have changed `objectname` to the object's name correct? And this code is in its step event?

Comment: @Timtech...yes i have changed the objectname to the player's name.  (obj_helicopter) and also I have put the code snippet in the obj_helicopter's step event. There is no error (just that text file is empty), it creates a log file and it even shows in the comment window that "Output in: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\gamename\\log.txt". I played the game for 40-50 seconds, do you think I should play the game longer to get some output. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Aks I have tried my best to fix this, so I uncompressed the part where I changed everything to a string and wrote it, and instead wrote them directly in as reals. Playing the game for even 10 seconds will give about 10 lines of output, as long as the object has been created.

Comment: @Timtech...I really appreciate all your help and effort!! I am facing the same condition, that it is creating the log file but file is empty. I am using this code in simple pong game and helicopter game. Just need to track the position of the left player in pong game and helicopter position in helicopter game. Is this code working in your project? Sorry for all the trouble.